# connectionString defaulting to production database.. Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, connection-string

I am learning asp.net mvc 4 on top of entity framework. There is a project at work I took over and I am trying to centralize the connection credentials depending on the environment (dev, test, prod) the application is in.

Currently I have the connectionstring dynamic, but for some reason entity framework ignores the connection string initial Catalog setting.

```
<connectionStrings>
 <add name="name1" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.csdl|res:  //*/Model.ssdl|res://*/Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=001\;Initial Catalog=**;Integrated Security=False;User ID=**;Password=**;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

<add name="name2" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Entites.csdl|res://*/Entites.ssdl|res://*/Entites.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=001\;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=**;password=**;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I have no idea what half of the stuff in the connectionString means, but it is the second connection string giving me troubles, "name2"

Running the debugger shows the base class that extends the ObjectContext called like so,

: base("name=name2", "name2")

I figured Initial Catalog was already set in the connectionstring, "name1" and that would transfer to the name2.. but for the heck of it I added the Initial Catalog to the second connection string and it still defaults to the wrong catalog. I am connecting to the same database server but we have a test and a production database..

What could be overriding this catalog setting and redirecting to the wrong database? When I run my code, I get an innerexception telling me the username (the test database username) doesn't have access to the production database, but I am not sure why the production database is being passed in.

Here is the exception:

The server principal "testuser" is not able to access the database "**ProductionName**" under the current security context.]

initializing ObjectContext

```
    public Entities() : base("name=name2", "name2")
    {
        this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
        OnContextCreated();
    }
```

This is also in the web.config files:

```
<entityFramework>
   <defaultConnectionFactory   type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
   <providers>
     <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient"  type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
   </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

Something else interesting I noticed. When I leave the Initial Catalog setting in on the "name2" connectionstring, and set to the test database, and all the credentials are correct, I get the original error as I posted. If I change the initial Catalog to the production name and leave the wrong credentials to log in, I get a log in failed error. Same if I change the credentials around and leave the test database in for the initial catalog. So it seems it's authenticating properly, but something else is a factor once the connection goes through?

Comment: is this connection from app.config of datamodel or web.config of hoster app?

Comment: This is from web.config

Comment: Just a thought. Can you try removing the backslash from the value of `data source=001\ ` so that it reads `data source=001`?

Comment: Could you please also show the code you use to initialize your ObjectContext?

Comment: I tried that, no luck.

Comment: @David Tansey,  sure.  The code is on my pc at work though and i won't be back in until after the holiday. So don't forget about me :) Thanks!

Comment: @David Tansey I added the constructor code.

Comment: So your name2 has InitialCatalog set? Because it's not in the code you posted.

Comment: No, it's only in the name1..  I did try putting it in the name2 as well, but didn't have any effect.  When the initialCatalog is set in name1, will that leave it defaulted to that Catalog setting for any further connection Strings?

Comment: I just don't understand where it could be overriding the connection. Are there any other factors to consider beyond what's in the code. Something database related possibly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else who stumbles across this problem. I finally figured it out. The other developer was referring to the production database explicitly in all of the stored procedures. I took out all the references and left the implicit call using the "use" statement that was injected implicitly during the export/import process..

Example:

USE [TestDatabase]    <---- this goes at top of procedure

Here was an explicit call to the production database:
FROM [productionDB].[dbo].[Table] table

just make it an implicit call like so:
FROM [dbo].[Table] table

If my solution is not the answer for you, I also stumbled across this bug in sql server 2008:

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/354291/the-server-principal-is-not-able-to-access-the-database-under-the-current-security-context-microsoft-sql-server-error-916

Comment: DB name should not be part of the query. This is a bad practice. For example, the DB name can be changed at any time without changing the scripts.